# How to get this simple ruby app to run on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have this in hi.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

    get '/hi' do
        "Hello World!"
    end
```

If I do `ruby hi.rb` and then go to the address in my web browser, I see a webpage that says "Hello World."

Then I pushed this up to Heroku, but it doesn't show it. Why?

Here's the output from heroku logs.

```
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-03-27T06:13:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-03-27T06:13:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-03-27T06:13:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-03-27T06:13:55+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET deep-sword-6479.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-27T06:13:55+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 71.131.178.68 - - [27/Mar/2012:06:13:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" deep-sword-6479.heroku.com
2012-03-27T06:13:57+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 71.131.178.68 - - [27/Mar/2012:06:13:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" deep-sword-6479.heroku.com
2012-03-27T06:13:57+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET deep-sword-6479.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-26T23:15:13-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-03-27T06:15:17+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by afontanilla@ucdavis.edu
2012-03-27T06:15:17+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 22af87a by afontanilla@ucdavis.edu
2012-03-27T06:15:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-03-27T06:15:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-03-26T23:15:17-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 42835 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]: <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- sinatra (LoadError)
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/hello.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-03-27T06
:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from 
/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-03-27T06:15:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-03-27T06:15:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-03-27T06:15:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-03-27T06:15:21+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET deep-sword-6479.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-27T06:15:21+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 71.131.178.68 - - [27/Mar/2012:06:15:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" deep-sword-6479.heroku.com
2012-03-27T06:15:30+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET deep-sword-6479.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-27T06:15:30+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 71.131.178.68 - - [27/Mar/2012:06:15:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" deep-sword-6479.heroku.com
2012-03-27T06:15:37+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET deep-sword-6479.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-27T06:15:39+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 71.131.178.68 - - [27/Mar/2012:06:15:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" deep-sword-6479.heroku.com
2012-03-27T06:17:16+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET deep-sword-6479.heroku.com/hi dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-27T06:17:16+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 85.115.194.158 - - [27/Mar/2012:06:17:16 +0000] "GET /hi HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.65 Safari/535.11" deep-sword-6479.heroku.com
2012-03-27T06:17:17+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET deep-sword-6479.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-27T06:17:17+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 85.115.194.158 - - [27/Mar/2012:06:17:17 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.65 Safari/535.11" deep-sword-6479.heroku.com
2012-03-27T06:22:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-03-27T06:22:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-03-27T06:22:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 31779 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]: <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- sinatra (LoadError)
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/hello.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-03-27T06:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-03-27T06:22:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-03-27T06:22:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Do a 'heroku logs'. Post results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hello.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Then create a **config.ru** file in the same directory

```
require './hello'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Then create **Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
```

git push heroku master,
You can see results here: http://glowing-dusk-8900.heroku.com/

more info [here](http://ididitmyway.heroku.com/past/2010/1/16/deploying_sinatra_apps_on_heroku/)

**EDIT:**

Comment: It seemed to work, but when I go to the web page it doesn't load. It's at  http://deep-sword-6479.heroku.com